# Creating a String from an Array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, string

I'm trying to create a string out of several array values like so:

```
$input = array("1140", "1141", "1142", "1144", "1143", "1102");
$rand_keys = array_rand($input, 2);
$str = "$input[$rand_keys[0]], $input[$rand_keys[1]]";
```

However, in the third line, I get this error:
Unexpected '[' expecting ']'

I thought that by converting the array to a value I would be able to use it in my string. What am I doing wrong with my syntax?

Comment: Why not just use `implode()`?

Comment: Because I need the order of the values to be random, I'm trying to learn how to initialize a string with array values.

Comment: This would read better without chance for php getting confused: `$str = $input[$rand_keys[0]] .', '. $input[$rand_keys[1]];` ... but for that, I'd definitely do what @JayBlanchard asked, and use implode.

Comment: `$str = "{$input[$rand_keys[0]]}, {$input[$rand_keys[1]]}";` should work. But +4 on an implode implementation. Much more readable.

Comment: @jh1711 Please post your comment as an answer so I can accept. It was just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to expand more than simple variables inside strings you need to use complex (curly syntax). [Link to manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php). You need to scroll down a little in the manual. Your last line of code will look like this:

```
$str = "{$input[$rand_keys[0]]}, {$input[$rand_keys[1]]}";
```

But you could also use implode to achieve the same result.

```
$str = implode(', ', [$rand_keys[0], $rand_keys[1]]);
```

It's up to you.

Comment: Thank you. This was just the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to fix your code, simply adjust that one line to this line:

```
$str = $input[$rand_keys[0]] .', '. $input[$rand_keys[1]];
```

Here are a couple of other nicer solutions:

```
shuffle($input);
$str = $input[0] .', '. $input[1];
```

Or:

```
shuffle($input);
$str = implode(', ',array_slice($input,0,2));
```

Comment: Personally I hate curly brace hell inside double quotes. But thats my preference, and entirely an opinionated viewpoint. YMMV.